# Logstash KV plugin working

Tags: logstash

I am trying to use logstash's KV plugin. I have following log format:
    time taken for transfer for all files in seconds=23 transfer start time= 201708030959 transfer end time = 201708030959

```
My .conf file has following KV plugin:
filter {    
    kv {     
        value_split => "=" 
    }   
}

When I run logstash, it parses complete log file line by line excluding the one having "=". I need seconds, start time and end time to be separated as key value pairs. Please suggest.
```

Comment: Can you include your logstash input? Are events separated by new line?

Comment: Hi , following is my input :    input {
 file
        {  
  path => [ "/var/opt/data/output.log" ]    
  start_position => "beginning"    
 }
}   I have log as below : time taken for transfer for all files in seconds=23 transfer start time= 201708030959 transfer end time = 201708030959.             There are many such log lines in the logs files along with some other log data. Like this: 1501754423----------------------process starte
A0000082587 ----->
TechSupport

Comment: I think, since kv use the space as the character to split between the key-value pairs and your keys are full of space, the kv filter don't know how to split the pairs. You might succeed with a grok filter.

Comment: I could parse all the data and could see that in Kibana. But for “time” key, it combines both the values in a single field. Like time = “201708030959 ,201708030959”. Which seems to be correct as per default implementation.

But , I need both the timings as separate fields like “start time = 201708030959” and “end time=201708030959”. So, that I can use them separately. How can we do that?